# <asp:RangeValidator> not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

The range validator for my textbox isn't working at all.

Any thoughts?

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panOdometerReading">
            <tr>
                <td class="label right">
                    <fastr:ControlLabel runat="server" ID="lblWarrantyOtherInformationOdometer"> 
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valWarrantyOtherInformationOdometer" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgOdometerTxt" ControlToValidate="txtOdometer" ErrorMessage="Please enter the vehicle's odometer reading.">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="valWarrantyOtherInformationOdometerRange" Enabled="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vgOdometerTxt" ControlToValidate="txtOdometer" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="999999" Type="Integer" ErrorMessage="Invalid odometer reading.">*</asp:RangeValidator>
                        <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="valWarrantyOtherInformationOdometerCustomeValidator" ValidationGroup="vgOdometerTxt" OnServerValidate="cvWarrantyOtherInformationOdometer_OnServerValidate" ControlToValidate="txtOdometer" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid odometer reading.">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        Odometer Reading
                    </fastr:ControlLabel>
                </td>
                <td class="formInput">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOdometer" Text='<%# Proposal.Vehicle != null ? Proposal.Vehicle.Odometer.ToString() : String.Empty %>' ValidationGroup="vgOdometerTxt" OnTextChanged="txtOdometer_OnTextChanged"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Cheers

Comment: Set the CausesValidation to false and explicitly call the Page.Validate() method.

Comment: What is mean by not working? Do you mean '*' does not appear if you enter value outside the given range?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the other validators are working (the asterisk appears) just not the range validation.